# Operator precedence for negate operator

Tags: antlr, antlr4

## Update: This is not an issue with ANTLR

It is a [bug](https://github.com/Strumenta/antlr-kotlin/pull/75) in the antlr-kotlin generator that I'm using.

## Original Question

I want to parse some mathematical expressions that contain variables. Here's my grammar:

```
expr
  : '-' expr                # Negate
  | expr ( '*' | '/' ) expr # MultDiv
  | expr ( '+' | '-' ) expr # AddSub
  | '(' expr ')'            # Paren
  | ID                      # Var
  | NUM                     # Num
  ;
```

But when I try to parse `-a + b`, I always get `-(a + b)` and not `(-a) + b`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. When I add the usual definitions for `ID` and `NUM` and skip white space, I get the parse tree `(expr (expr - (expr a)) + (expr b))` for your input, which is equivalent to `(-a) + b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by sepp2k in the comments, this is not reproducible:

[image]